# Distribution of 'DFSTAT'

Tags: regression, distributions, linear, convolution

Apart from the commonly applied "influence measures" in linear regression, i.e. dfbeta(s) / Cook's distance / covratio / dffit(s) / studentized residuals / leverage, there is one not so famous, mentioned in a footnote on page 14 in Belsey, Kuh and Welsch (1980): DFSTAT, also termed DFSTUD.
If $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x + \varepsilon$ and the leave-one-out model is $y_{(-i)} = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{(-i)} + \varepsilon$, then w.r.t. the slope $\beta_1$, DFSTAT is the difference of its $t$-statistic

$\mathrm{DFSTAT} = \Delta t = t_{\beta1} - t_{\beta1(-i)} = \frac{\beta_1}{\mathrm{s.e.}(\beta_1)} - \frac{\beta_1(-i)}{\mathrm{s.e.}(\beta_1(-i))}$

where s.e. = standard error of the estimate.
In contrast to all other influence measures, this is the only one with a direct relation to statistical inference.
What would be the best approach to construct a new $t$-distribution which is a result of subtracting the two corresponding scaled/shifted $t$-distributions $t(\beta_1, se(\beta_1), \nu_1)$ and $t(\beta_1(-i), se(\beta_1(-i), \nu_1-1)$ that results from DFSTAT? Convolution? Bivariate $t$-distribution? I believe one should take the correlation structure of the full linear model and the leave-one-out model into consideration...